# Filtra UseAgent Via Database

Tags: php, mysql

Criei uma tabela que recebe algumas informações do visitante, ID, UseAgent, Address e proxy.

Estou fazendo um gráfico tipo aqueles torta (pie chart) e gostaria de mostrar a quantidade de visitas de Y navegadores e X de outros.

Ex: os 3 navegadores mais ultilizados e o quarto numero seria "outros".

Pensei em vários metódos para fazer isso, já que existe um campo chamado UseAgent que recebe $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] pensei pesquisar com o WHERE LIKE, mas para isso eu preciso fazer uma lista de strings, existe outra maneira mais fácil, sem modificar a DB ?

Comment: `sem modificar a DB` é uma coisa que não podemos garantir, já que você não especificou como estão sendo salvos. Está gravando direto com `HTTP_USER_AGENT`?

Comment: Apesar de eu já ter respondido, qual o o problema em usar o [Google Analytics integrado ao Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/analytics/solutions/articles/gdataAnalyticsCharts)?

Answer (score 1):

Se eu fosse fazer um LOG de estatísticas, iria usar uma TBL temporária para guardar as informações cruas - ID, UseAgent, Address, Referrer... cada um em um campo

> <sub>BasicLog:
>
>   `ID | UseAgent | Referrer`</sub>

São dados bem brutos e você não precisa deles on-time.
O próximo passo seria converter em estatística. Eu criaria uma TBL com as demais informações que podem ser obtidas( browser, versão, SO, IP, referrer, data-hora...)

> <sub>Stats:
>
>   browser | versão | SO | IP | referrer | time | page</sub>

Basicamente você vai rodar um script para pegar as informações em BasicLog, extrair as informações, salvar em Stats e pode limpar os de BasicLog.
Assim você pode ter todas as informações individualizadas prontas para gerar um gráfico com todas informações dos acessos, páginas mais acessadas...

Comment: eu estava fazendo do jeito que você mencionou, mas a minha classe não estava tão boa assim, então criei uma nova mas que agora armazena o UseAgent.

Answer (score 1):

Em meio as muitas pesquisas que fiz quando programava ativamente, cheguei a elaborar [essa classe](https://github.com/nextframework/next/blob/dev/HTTP/Request/Browser.php) para obtenção de informações diversas sobre o browser do usuário.

O uso, assumindo que a classe tenha sido incluída, é simples:

```
$browser = new Browser;

print '<pre>'; print_r( $browser -> getInfo() );
```

E o retorno:

```
Browser Object
(
    [agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/36.0.1985.125 Safari/537.36
    [browser] => Chrome
    [version] => 36.0.1985.125
    [platform] => Windows
    [isMobile] => 
    [isRobot] => 
    [IP] => 
)
```

Dessa forma você não precisa armazenar o *user-agent*, depois consultá-lo e analisar suas as informações pra armazenar de novo, consultar esses dados analisados e só então montar o gráfico.

Existem algumas considerações a serem feitas:

- Esse componente fazia parte de uma coisa maior e, por isso, existem dependências. No entanto, é perfeitamente possível remover tais dependências simplesmente por remover a declaração do *namespace* (e o *use* logo abaixo) e alterar `extends Object`por `extends stdClass`.
- No *output* acima temos algumas entradas vazias.

  - **isMobile**
    Quando a Requisição se originou de um dispositivo *mobile* está entrada é setada como **TRUE**.
  - **isRobot**
    Quando a Requisição foi feita por um *webcrawler* (Googlebot e cia.) esta entrada é setada como **TRUE**.

  Não é que elas não estejam funcionando, ocorre que estou usando um [print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) e, para ele, **FALSE**, que são os valores das entradas nesse momento, não aparecem.
- Ainda no *output* temos a entrada referente ao IP do usuário. Igualmente ao problema citado acima, [print_r()](http://www.php.net/print_r) não mostra **NULL**.

  E essa entrada só não está aparecendo pois a rotina que detecta o IP do usuário, se apoia em [getenv()](http://www.php.net/getenv) e eu estou, no momento, rodando em CLI, onde informações de ambiente devem ser setadas manualmente.

Comment: Permita-me discordar do momento em que deve ser executado? Estatísticas são informações de acompanhamento não devem interferir no sistema, logo, não acho que devam ser processadas imediatamente.

Comment: Realmente é um ponto válido, mas venhamos e convenhamos que nem todo site é como o Google né? Não sei quando que as estatísticas de um determinado relatório do Analytics são de fato computados, se diária ou semanalmente, mas para nós, mortais, nem sempre é assim que a banda toca e é até viável antecipar esse tio de dado.

Comment: Sem dúvida para sites pequenos pode não importar muito. Acredito que os sites de monitoramento trabalhem desta forma, até pelo `delay`, em parte pelas ferramentas de análise como um todo. Vejo estatísticas como análise humana, webcrawler não computariam páginas visitadas e fraudes devem ser observadas, sendo assim serão mais regras e exceções que vão ser processadas - por isso eu separo o momento de produzi-las. A sua classe poderia trabalhar com um `Request` separado, ai poderia usar as duas classes em conjunto

Comment: Se você fuçar nesse repositório vai ver que dois níveis acima tem uma classe Request separada, hehe.

Comment: Não tinha visto :) Isso torna a classe boa para servir como uma LIB. Eu vou dar uma consultada com calma